# Reversi Valid Move Algorithm

Tags: c

The problem I having right now is that I am not sure if my code is logically correct so I asking for help and opinions

dir is an enum from enum direction. Basically there is eight directions exp: NORTH, NORTHWEST, NORTHEAST etc.

So each direction, I would scan if there is a token either the player's, opponent's or if it is blank

y is the y-coordinates and x is the x-coordinates. In this code, I am looking north of the player coordinates.

```
for(dir = NORTH; dir <= SOUTH_WEST; dir++){
    if(dir == NORTH){
        for(int i = 1; i <= BOARD_HEIGHT - y; i++){
//If there is no token, it would return false
            if(board[y+1][x] == BLANK){ 
                return FALSE;
            }
//if there is the player's token, it would return false
            if else(board[y+1][x] == player_token){ 
                return FALSE;
            }
//if there is the opponents token, it would continue up till it finds the player's token, if not then it would return false.
            if else(board[y+i][x] != player_token){ 
                if(board[y+i][x] == player_token){
                    captured_pieces++;
                }
                else{
                    return FALSE;
                }    

            }

        }
    }
}
```

If there is any room for improving, then please tell me

Comment: You're looping over all directions, but then you only do something with `NORTH`. Even if you add branches for every direction, that structure will do exactly the same thing as every branch, in order, without condition.

Comment: I don't see a real technical question in here.

Answer (score 0):

The first two `if` statements can be moved outside the inner `for` loop.

Replace `if else` with `else if` (you should be getting errors from the compiler).

The check for player/opponent token doesn't check for opponent piece at all.
I suggest the following rewrite:

```
//if there is the opponents token, it would continue up till it finds the player's token, if not then it would return false.
            switch (board[y+i][x]){ 
                case opponent_token:
                    // Another token potentially captured
                    captured_pieces++;
                case player_token:
                    // Stop counting
                    break;
                default:
                    // Empty square
                    return FALSE;
                }    

            }
```

After the inner loop, you need to check that there actually was a `player_token`. If loop terminated because it reached the end of the board, return FALSE.

Comment: Is there another way of writing opponent_token, like something similar to '!='?

Comment: A `switch` expression can always be written using  `if/else if/else` instead.